# Deploying Laravel 7 on Centos on Nginx with Apache running

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx, centos7

I am trying to deploy my Laravel application into a private server that is currently running Apache on Centos.  I do understand that I need to run this on a different port since apache is currently running the server, this is my .conf file.

/conf.d/apt-api.conf

```
server {
    listen      81;
       server_name _;
       root        /var/www/html/apt-api/public;
       index       index.php;

       charset utf-8;
       gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript text/javascript application/x-javascript  image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
```

sites-available

```
server {
         listen 81;


         # Log files for Debugging
         access_log /var/log/nginx/mint-api-access.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/mint-api-error.log;

         # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
         root /var/www/html/apt-api/public;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;

         # Your Domain Name
         server_name default_server;

         location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         }

         # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
         location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
         }
 }
```

I do have a symlik in sites-enable.

However, when I try to test an api route, i get:

```
nginx error!
The page you are looking for is not found.
```

Accessing it in this way.

```
http://SERVER_API:81/api/appointments
```

Any Ideas why?

Comment: did you have restart the nginx server?

Comment: @HOSSAINAZADSHOHAG, yes, I restarted nginx.

Comment: All that `sites-enabled`, `sites-available` etc. is a Debian/Ubuntu/etc. specific stuff. CentOS nginx builds usually use individual files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` for individual domains and don't use `sites-available` or `sites-enabled`. However either in Debian-based or RHEL-based distros you can organize nginx configs in whatever-you-want way. What exactly distro you have on your server? What are those two files `/conf.d/apt-api.conf` and `sites-available` and why are they different? Where are they physically located on your server?